# AWS:Add json object to dynamodb

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have this particular scenario

1) I have an angular app on localhost.

2)The angular app is supposed to send a JSON object.

3)The JSON object will be stored in AWS dynamodb table.

Any idea how i can achieve point#3.

Store the json object in dynamodb.
After each push of the button , it will do the same task again and again.
My angular app has CRUD options.
Any idea how i should go about doing that particular task ie linking the CRUD options to dynamodb.

Best Regards.

Answer (score -1):

Try AmazonClient someway like this:

```
var params = {
  TableName : 'Table',
  Item: {
     HashKey: 'haskey',
     NumAttribute: 1,
     BoolAttribute: true,
     ListAttribute: [1, 'two', false],
     MapAttribute: { foo: 'bar'},
     NullAttribute: null
  }
};

var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

documentClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(data);
});
```

Documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#put-property).